# Why is this javascript getting permission denied?

Tags: javascript

> ```
> Permission denied for <http://example.com> to get property
> ```
>
> HTMLDocument.body from
>   http://www.example.com.

```
var c = parseFloat(cf.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight) + 30;
```

Comment: NSFW alert - that domain is registered - I almost opened it from my office. @MitMaro

Comment: Just a place holder page for me, so not registered. But still NSFW, can someone edit in `example.com` and `www.example.com` instead.

Comment: are you trying to access properties of another window?

Comment: YES I try to access the properties of another window, and the domain is not xxx.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) implemented by most (all??) browsers. Simply put `example.com` is not the same origin as `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

With a little guessing about your question, I see 2 possibilies:

1. Javascript will not let you read data from other domains via Ajax, and you read from a domain different than example.com
2. You read data from example.com, but you really try to read from www.example.com, and the webserver only serves on www.example.com.